# Opening remote pdf file with valid path returns 404

Tags: php, drupal, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to display the respective PDF file associated with an article in drupal so that if the browser is equipped of rendering the pdf it should open directly, if not show a conventional dialog with 'Open', 'Save' and 'Cancel' allowing the user to choose among the options. The PDFs are present in a public web server where all resources like images and files are accessible.

The code I'm using to accomplish is as below:

```
$pdf_file_name = "http://mysite.com/valid-pdf-file.pdf";
drupal_set_header('Content-type: application/pdf');
drupal_set_header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $pdf_file_name
 . '"');
$fp = fopen($pdf_file_name, "r");
$file_open_timeout = 60;
if ($fp) {
  stream_set_timeout($fp, $file_open_timeout); 
  while (!feof($fp)) {
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush();
  }
  fclose($fp);
}
else {
  watchdog("pdf logging", "Could not open the file " . $pdf_file_name);
}
```

Though this code worked for some of my initial pdf files (which I assume were small ones upto 10 MB), it failed on many other files with the following error message:

> fopen(http://mysite.com/valid-pdf-file.pdf): failed to open stream:
>   HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Opening the path to that file http://mysite.com/valid-pdf-file.pdf through the browser directly renders the file without any error message. Hence I tried the `stream_set_timeout` in the above code based on some googling but still can't get past the 404 error despite the file certainly being present.

Here's an example of how one of the URLs that failed to open would look like:

"http://fileservername.com/resources/sitename/2013/03/20/bed6e3de-41bf-4bf9-bed8-d21508eaa8ca/Trouble --Cloud Compendium optimized.pdf"

I also tested with url encoding the file path but the result was no different; did `urlencode($pdf_file_name)` in the fopen and readfile.

Further I checked if the file/folder permissions of these troublesome pdf files was any different from those that open properly but found that it was no different.

An alternate code for this file handling

```
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($pdf_file_name);
exit();
```

gave the same results where the troublesome pdfs returned 404 while the others worked fine. Any suggestions on what I'm missing out to get this functional or a better implementation of this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show a real-life URL that is failing. Chances are the issue is in the file name. 404 errors are pretty clear cut, there's a problem with the requested location. Browsers are much more intelligent when working out how to correctly URL-encode user input, so URL-encoding is likely the solution, but we would need to see the actual URL you are trying to load (you can obfuscate the domain name if you want)

Comment: Might want to make sure that url wrappers are enabled for fopen (http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) and that DNS resolution on your server is working correctly - does a simple command line wget http://pathto.pdf/file work?

Comment: @shannonman Neither of those issues would result in a HTTP 404. If URL wrappers were disabled the error would tell you so, and if DNS wasn't working you wouldn't get as far as contacting the remote server to get a 404 error response.

Comment: @DaveRandom and @shannonman Thank you both for the response; I've updated the question with what is more or less the URL as I cannot use the real URL due to restrictions, also with my attempt to encode the URL that failed.. `allow_url_fopen` is indeed on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is indeed URL encoding, but you can't just `urlencode()` the whole string because this will also escape some characters that need to be left intact. I would suggest something like this:

```
function escape_url($url)
{
    // Check that the input data is sane
    if (!$parts = parse_url($url)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!isset($parts['scheme'], $parts['host'])) {
        return false;
    }

    // construct site base URL
    $result = $parts['scheme'] . '://';

    if (isset($parts['user'])) {
        $result .= $parts['user'];
        if (isset($parts['pass'])) {
            $result .= ':' . $parts['pass'];
        }
        $result .= '@';
    }

    $result .= $parts['host'];

    // Normalize path
    if (!isset($parts['path'])) {
        // if no path assume domain root
        $parts['path'] = '/';
    }
    $parts['path'] = preg_split('#/+#', $parts['path']); // split to path components
    $parts['path'] = array_map(function($part) { // ensure all components are correctly escaped
        return urlencode(urldecode($part));
    }, $parts['path']);
    $parts['path'] = implode('/', $parts['path']); // reconstruct string
    $result .= $parts['path'];

    // parse the query string an rebuild it
    if (isset($parts['query'])) {
        parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
        if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            // undo magic_quotes
            array_walk_recursive($query, function(&$value) {
                $value = preg_replace('#\\\\([\'"\\\\\\x00])#', '$1', $value);
            });
        }
        $result .= '?' . http_build_query($query);
    }

    // add document fragment if present
    if (isset($parts['fragment'])) {
        $result .= '#' . $parts['fragment'];
    }

    return $result;
}

$url = 'http://fileservername.com/resources/sitename/2013/03/20/bed6e3de-41bf-4bf9-bed8-d21508eaa8ca/Trouble --Cloud Compendium optimized.pdf';
echo escape_url($url);
// output:
// http://fileservername.com/resources/sitename/2013/03/20/bed6e3de-41bf-4bf9-bed8-d21508eaa8ca/Trouble+--Cloud+Compendium+optimized.pdf
```

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/nDT4v6)

**Note:** This uses [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to normalize any query string that may be on the URL, which is affected by the [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) configuration option. **This option is deprecated, unsafe and should be disabled**, but you should be aware that if it is enabled it will affect the output of this function. It is not possible to adjust this setting at runtime, you need to ensure that the setting is disabled in your environment.

**Edit** corrected potential double-encoding of path components, added fix for when `magic_quotes` screws things up. Note that these fixes uses a closures so require PHP 5.3+, for lower versions [`create_function()`](http://php.net/create-function) or helper functions can be substituted.